# Terminal showing Unknown, how to fix it?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, zsh

Every time I open my Terminal app in Mac, the first string it shows is this

```
marcosantos@Unknown
```

Well, I know that `marcosantos` is my username. But what is this `Unknown` part, what should it actually display, why is it displaying `Unknown` and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not a Mac person but that string is typically the leftmost part of the hostname (up to but excluding the first .)

Answer (score 0):

Unknown is the name of the computer.  You can change it by going to system preferences -> sharing and then changing the name at the top.  I think you need to then restart your computer for it to take.